# PagingMemory Proxy is not getting refreshed when the store is updated using removeAt(rowindex)

Tags: extjs, pagingtoolbar

I am unable to understand the behavior of PagingMemoryProxy in EXTJS 3.4.
  a. It is defined as follows:

```
proxy:new Ext.ux.data.PagingMemoryProxy(jsonData),
listeners : {
load : {
scope : this,
fn : function(actorStore) {
var r = actorStore.getRange();
        var modified = actorStore.getModifiedRecords();
            for ( var i = 0; i < modified.length; i++) {
                      for (j = 0; j < r.length; j++) {
                           if (r[j].get('plannedResourceId') == modified[i].get('plannedResourceId')) {
                                 var changes = modified[i].getChanges();
                                    for (p in changes) {
                                         if (changes.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                                         r[j].set(p, changes[p]);
                            }}}}}}}}
```

So, the problem what i encountered was when i delete a row using:

```
gridPanelToRefresh.getStore().removeAt(value.value.rowIndex);
```

After performing this above mentioned task, when i click on refresh button at that    time, the deleted data comes in the grid too. I mean the store which was created using the proxy mentioned above is not getting  refreshed.

Can you please suggest some solutions for the same. One lead i got on the same is getModifiedRecords() does not gets the deleted records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Best possible approach when dealing with above query is.
Following points i have came through while dealing with the issue.

a. The problem was not with the Paging Memory at all. Because it is doing its task perfectly. One thing to take a note in this is whenever we Delete a record at that time the most vital properties namely -
*modifiedRecords, dirty* are never changed so that was the reason why my paging toolbar was not getting updated json as it uses :

```
  var modified = actorStore.getModifiedRecords();
```

As a result, getmodifiedRecords() returns nothing at all.

Implemenation approach - when my JSONdata is loaded at that time i store it at Global scope and then update that JSON using splice and then upload it to the store whenever a delete event is performed.

```
  for (var i = 0; i < (jsonData.total); i++) {
        if(i == indexForRemoval) {
           jsonData.data.splice(indexForRemoval,1);
        }
    }
          jsonData.total = ((jsonData.total) - 1);
```

Hope this helps.